# How can I remap Application Key to Command Key using Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-layout, macos-ventura

I have been using the Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 for many years as it saves me from tendonitis and other Repetitive Stress Injury (RSI) problems.

The 3 lower-left keys on this keyboard are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Windows</kbd> & <kbd>Alt</kbd> (left->right order). MacOS (e.g. Ventura 13.5.2)  interprets these as `Ctrl`, `Command` (i.e. "splat") & `Option`.  This works fine.

The 3 lower-right keys (right->left) are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Application</kbd> & <kbd>Alt</kbd>. MacOS interprets these as `Ctrl`, `<nothing>` & `Option`.  That is, hitting the <kbd>Application</kbd> key has no effect and is ignored by MacOS.

I want my keyboard to be symmetric like a normal Mac keyboard. That is, I want to have a Command Key on each side of the spacebar. How can I remap the <kbd>Application</kbd> key to be Command key on MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to download and use the free utility [**Karabiner-Elements**](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/).  In particular, you want to remap the "Application" key to be "Left-Command" key.

The Karabiner website has excellent instructions (with screenshots!) for both installation, security configuration, and key remapping.

Enjoy!